# Command rails g controller is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10

My version of ruby: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
My version of rails: Rails 4.1.8
I have a Windows 10. I installed railsinstaller with ruby 2.1.

My problem is:

When I use command: rails new hello_app I get app hello, OK.
But when I use command: rails g controller hello index or rails s then I get:

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Usage:   rails new APP_PATH
>   [options]
>
> Options:   -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      #
>   Path to the Ruby binary of your choice ... This generates a skeletal
>   Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
>       See the README in the newly created application to get going.

I want to work with Ruby on Rails on Windows 10, so if this is possibly, I want solutions without VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options]

Is a warning , DL is used by ruby to serve external sources . Which is more connected to the SSL support and secure package management. So , if you ask me , what to do , I would say ,

- Try [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) for the windows.[ Without VM ]
- Or , you can try the Linux Distro like Ubuntu , Debian Or , RPM based system . I would highly recommend use any linux other than windows. Or , other unix like Mac
- Thanks to you - you can add up the `C:/` path before execution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thx for help. Maybe I'm stupid, but what I only need is typing cd C:... for my app before trying to generate controller. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: if this was the solution then you just can mark your solution as right answer. You will get points for that. But please , do try to move into unix system if you are thinking to work on rails for a long time. And you also can use unix like terminal for windows which will make these things easier for you. But I am going to add these in my answer now.